# What is the lastest SEO technology used by Google?

Tags: seo, search-engine

What is the  latest SEO technology used by Google?

Comment: Ohh, a crystal-ball question :D... I keep myself tuned.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not from Google, and I do not intend to answer you question directly since no one out side Google knows what they do and Googlers are not allowed to tell you this kind of info I guess. It occurs to me, though,that WikiLeak provide you some secretes as US diplomatic cable does. Just kidding:-)

That being said, there are some approaches that are encouraged by Google, used by Google and most importantly worked for me in the past couple of years.

Link. I am sure you know how many in-bound links does Google have. Well not exactly, but you know the point, link still counts. Try your best to build relevant links, both in bound links and on site links. Good link not only helps your SEO, but also boosts your referring traffic.

Content. It is our king, if your web site does not like say, Google(it has tons of links), then you'd better provide great content, like Stackoverflow does. The most thing that makes SO so exceptional on search engines ranking is that SO provides the best content, unique and fresh.

Semantic web code. HTML related stuff like title, h, mata, atl and so forth. Web server involved thing like clean URL,  and URL rewrite, 301 redirect. Moreover, loading speed of your site is also important. Just name few.

Your users behavior. I am not sure about this, but some people write somewhere on Stackover that your web site's click through rate from Google's search result page, on site time, bounce rate also count. I do not believe this actually because it sounds like Google is watch us like big brother. But considering so many web site are using Google Analytics, it is still possible. Anyway, if you provide great content, with sound code, and useful links, you users love it, and arguably Google loves it.

Have fun and come back Stackoverflow, I am sure you gonna learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

this is how different tags a ranked

1 title

2 headline(h1)

3 meta description

4 h2

5 h3 etc